Is the strong nuclear force same for a quark-antiquark and 2 different color of quarks?
consider a 2 quark system up red and anti up red quark and then consider a 3 quark system up red and up green(i am only interested in these 2 quarks in the system, so there is a 3rd quark, for instance, down blue. but ignore it and contributions by it). I wonder that if the forces between these quarks are the same or not? Consider every other variable of quarks are same and also ignore other forces(EM force etc.)

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
